# Poor little thing. it didn't deserve this

Tags: knowledge

What creature lives in the sea and is sometimes 1,000 times more valuable when injured than when at full health?

Comment: I can really think of way too many things that satisfy this. A whale (gets sick pukes valuable ambergris, but cant be hunted normally.) A duck (foie gras) Slow loris (sold on black market after deteethed).

Comment: but is that sometimes 1,000 times more valuable?

Comment: If you can't hunt the whale then its value is \$0, maybe you can sell a picture of it for \$10. But if it pukes up a big chunk of ambergris that could sell for \$10,000. Also we "injure" trees to make them shorter so its easier to pick the fruit. A 40 foot tall orange tree is a pain, but a 10-15 foot tall injured one is much more valuable.

Comment: still not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Horns/tusks? Another possibility is some creature depicted on different forms of currency.

Comment: I think you should disclose the answer - even if more answers were posted, I don't think we'll advance very much, as this question lacks direction.

Comment: Time for a hint then.

Comment: Octopus.  The ink they release when threatened is very valuable.

Comment: Is 1000 a hard-and-fast number, or an approximation?

Comment: This cannot be answered normally, but I would hazard a guess at an oyster, since it requires an irritant to begin creating the pearl.

Comment: Yay, I think i have the answer and its should be right. Is it [this](http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/sea-shell-pearl-inside-41486733.jpg)?

Comment: @tfitzger i was just searching for the pic and u beat me by seconds haha.

Comment: Welcome to the site. First "puzzles" can be tricky, but we can all improve over time... Hint: While the answer might be *cool*, your question really is a *quiz* and not a *puzzle*. (And therefore off-topic.) If you want to make this into a *puzzle* use the same idea within a riddle (as a part of it) with some other hints and a fair chance to find a *single* fitting answer, i.e. mulitple ways to rule *other* answers out. Then you can "utilize" your idea properly instead of just posting it as a "Guess what I'm thinking off" type quiz. (Does not have to be a riddle, but that came to mind.)

Comment: It is in fact an oyster, @tfitzger put it into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Parzival Unfortunately, I cannot because the puzzle is too vague and has been put on hold. Until the hold is listed, new answers cannot be added.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A Maple tree. Ok wood, but very common. Jam one of these things in it[image] and you have a consistent source of delicious sap and income.

Comment: I like your thinking, but not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: underwater maple tree...?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to call him a creature, because - well he is one.

> George Bailey, from *It's a Wonderful Life*

Here's the scene:

> George walks into Mr Potter's office to ask for a loan.  He offers his insurance policy as security.  His policy covers his death, and he is broke right now, therefore he is worth more dead than alive, and quite possibly 1000 times more.

Comment: I like your thinking, but still no.